# How to avoid last column values being repeated when reading Excel file with unknown number of columns using U-SQL

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

I am trying to read an Excel file with oh22is ExcelExtractor library and write in a csv file in Azure Datalake. The Excel file is in problematic tabular format, and the number of columns is unknown (increasing by month).

The only keyword that I found to be working with this custom extractor is the EXTRACT. My approach was to extract as many Excel columns as I could possibly want starting from [A] ([A], [B] ... [AA], [AB]..). I am getting my data out, but the problem is last column values are repeating.

**U-SQL:**

```
USE DATABASE master;

REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [DocumentFormat.OpenXml];
REFERENCE ASSEMBLY [oh22is.Analytics.Formats];

DECLARE @ExcelFile = @SourceFolderPath+@SourceFileName;

@Resources = 
    EXTRACT [A] string, [B] string, [C] string, [D] string, [E] string, [F] string, [G] string, [H] string, [I] string, [J] string, [K] string, [L] string, [M] string, [N] string, [O] string, [P] string, [Q] string, [R] string, [S] string, [T] string, [U] string, [V] string, [W] string, [X] string, [Y] string, [Z] string, [AA] string,  [AB] string,  [AC] string,  [AD] string,  [AE] string,  [AF] string,  [AG] string,  [AH] string,  [AI] string,  [AJ] string,  [AK] string,  [AL] string,  [AM] string,  [AN] string,  [AO] string,  [AP] string,  [AQ] string,  [AR] string,  [AS] string,  [AT] string,  [AU] string,  [AV] string,  [AW] string,  [AX] string,  [AY] string,  [AZ] string,  [BA] string,  [BB] string,  [BC] string,  [BD] string,  [BE] string,  [BF] string,  [BG] string,  [BH] string,  [BI] string,  [BJ] string,  [BK] string,  [BL] string,  [BM] string,  [BN] string,  [BO] string,  [BP] string,  [BQ] string,  [BR] string,  [BS] string,  [BT] string,  [BU] string,  [BV] string,  [BW] string,  [BX] string,  [BY] string,  [BZ] string,  [CA] string,  [CB] string,  [CC] string,  [CD] string,  [CE] string,  [CF] string,  [CG] string,  [CH] string,  [CI] string,  [CJ] string,  [CK] string,  [CL] string,  [CM] string,  [CN] string,  [CO] string,  [CP] string,  [CQ] string,  [CR] string,  [CS] string,  [CT] string,  [CU] string,  [CV] string,  [CW] string,  [CX] string,  [CY] string,  [CZ] string,  [DA] string,  [DB] string,  [DC] string,  [DD] string,  [DE] string,  [DF] string,  [DG] string,  [DH] string,  [DI] string,  [DJ] string,  [DK] string,  [DL] string,  [DM] string,  [DN] string,  [DO] string,  [DP] string,  [DQ] string,  [DR] string,  [DS] string,  [DT] string,  [DU] string,  [DV] string,  [DW] string,  [DX] string,  [DY] string,  [DZ] string,  [EA] string,  [EB] string,  [EC] string,  [ED] string,  [EE] string,  [EF] string,  [EG] string,  [EH] string,  [EI] string,  [EJ] string,  [EK] string,  [EL] string,  [EM] string,  [EN] string,  [EO] string,  [EP] string,  [EQ] string,  [ER] string,  [ES] string,  [ET] string,  [EU] string,  [EV] string,  [EW] string,  [EX] string,  [EY] string,  [EZ] string,  [FA] string,  [FB] string,  [FC] string,  [FD] string,  [FE] string,  [FF] string,  [FG] string,  [FH] string,  [FI] string,  [FJ] string,  [FK] string,  [FL] string,  [FM] string,  [FN] string,  [FO] string,  [FP] string,  [FQ] string,  [FR] string,  [FS] string,  [FT] string,  [FU] string,  [FV] string,  [FW] string,  [FX] string,  [FY] string,  [FZ] string,  [GA] string,  [GB] string,  [GC] string,  [GD] string,  [GE] string,  [GF] string,  [GG] string,  [GH] string,  [GI] string,  [GJ] string,  [GK] string,  [GL] string,  [GM] string,  [GN] string,  [GO] string,  [GP] string,  [GQ] string,  [GR] string,  [GS] string,  [GT] string,  [GU] string,  [GV] string,  [GW] string,  [GX] string,  [GY] string,  [GZ] string,  [HA] string,  [HB] string,  [HC] string,  [HD] string,  [HE] string,  [HF] string,  [HG] string,  [HH] string,  [HI] string,  [HJ] string,  [HK] string,  [HL] string,  [HM] string,  [HN] string,  [HO] string,  [HP] string,  [HQ] string,  [HR] string,  [HS] string,  [HT] string,  [HU] string,  [HV] string,  [HW] string,  [HX] string,  [HY] string,  [HZ] string
    FROM @ExcelFile
    USING new oh22is.Analytics.Formats.ExcelExtractor("Ark1");

OUTPUT @Resources
TO "/unpivotBasic1.txt"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

**Output:**

```
Column1   Column2   Column3   Column4   Column5   Column6   Column7   Column8   Column9   Column10   Column11   Column12   Column13   Column14   Column15   Column16   Column17   Column18   Column19   Column20   Column21   Column22   Column23   Column24   Column25   Column26   Column27   Column28   Column29   Column30   Column31   Column32   Column33   Column34   Column35   Column36   Column37   Column38   Column39   Column40   Column41   Column42   Column43   ...   Column226
SUM:         36,8      40,2      45,6     45,85     55,05      59,1      51,4      49,1       49,3          0       39,8       39,6       44,5       45,2         45       41,5       44,3       46,8       46,7       46,5       46,5          0         41       41,9       41,3       41,1       27,5       17,6         18       12,3       11,3        8,8          8          0        7,8        7,8        7,4        7,4        7,4        7,4        7,4        7,4   ...         7,4
ÅR           2019                          2020                                                                                                                            2021                                                                                                                                2022                                                                                                                                                             ...  
Mnd       Oktober   November  Desember   Januar    Februar     Mars      April      Mai       Juni       Juli     August  September    Oktober    November   Desember    Januar     Februar    Mars        April       Mai        Juni       Juli     August  September    Oktober    November   Desember    Januar    Februar       Mars       April       Mai       Juni       Juli     August  September    Oktober   November   November   November   November   November   ...    November
```

Output is correct except for columns [AN] to [HZ] (Column40 to Column234) which repeat the values from column [AM] or Column39 which is the last column with data in the original Excel. How can I get rid of these duplicate values or what am I doing wrong? End goal is to unpivot this data into 'Year', 'Month' and 'SUM' columns.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code in [oh22is.Analytics.Formats](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/Samples/ExcelExtractor/oh22is.Analytics.Formats/ExcelExtractor.cs) the reason found out to be pretty obvious. Last cell value is not removed/updated by the loop structure. Made a fix in my desk drawer:
[AzureDataLake-GitHub](https://github.com/Sweco-fivanl/AzureDataLake/commit/1acc5afb86f2621f30277bf9869c69077036739e)